# Wordpress plugin not working with theme

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm having trouble getting a plugin to work on a live WordPress site that I'm doing some amendments to (designed by someone else).
This is the page in question:
http://www.thecareercollective.co.uk/map/

I've replicated the site on my local machine so I can test things without affecting the live site. I've got to the point where it's this custom theme which the plugin does not work with. I've changed the theme to twentytwelve & twentythirteen and the plugin works fine.

In the custom theme the  isn't linking to this css file:
http://www.mysite/wp-content/plugins/image-map-hotspot/css/jquery.hotspot.min.css?ver=3.9.1

When I test it locally with a different theme the above css file appears at the very bottom of the  tag after the  tag:

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any code of the initialization of this plugin. It could be a problem when initializing. This may seem stupid but is the plugin definitely activated. Is there any errors coming through in the log which you could post and also possibly posting the themes functions.php could be helpful as it may show it stopping plugins.

Comment: The function.php file is very sparse:                               <?php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'leftsidebar',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h4>',
        'after_title' => '</h4>',
    ));


}
?>

Comment: I wouldnt know how to capture code of the plugin initialising. The plugin is definitely activated. No errors in the log as far as i can see.

Comment: The code will be in `wp-content/plugins/plugin-name` and it will be in one of the files. Just done a bit of googling and it looks like the plugin you're using is a paid plugin from codecanyon. Maybe you could try and contact the creators?

Comment: I tried that but they said there is an error in the shortcodes.js file (another plugin entirely) -   TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery(document).on') - although I couldn't find the error myself.

Comment: Maybe it's the theme's fault. Delete everything from its `functions.php` and go bringing stuff back until things break.

Comment: I'll try that. There's not much in the functions file to start with. (see above comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just an issue with your template jQuery and Plugin jQuery. Have a look which jQuery is being used by plugin and template. Both are using jQuery versions which conflicts with on another. Simply remove the confliction jQuery from the plugin and it will work.

Comment: What php file tells me which version of jQuery is being used?

Comment: Check in functions.php of template and plugin's function file or main activation file of plugin. There you will be able to see all files listed. Something like jquery.min.js?v1.1 or something like that. If you can share link to your website i can help you to diagnose it.

Comment: This is the web page. There should be animated pins hovering above the map:   http://www.thecareercollective.co.uk/map/

Comment: When i hover over the pin, it shows animated box. What is not working?

Comment: I fixed it now thanks. I had to add 3 lines of script to the header.php file of the plugin. 2 JQuery files and a CSS file. Thanks for all the advice :)

Comment: Am Glad that it helped. B.T.W you can accept my answer. :)